# Which is the preferred method when using/calling colors in android?

Tags: android, colors

E.G. **#FFFFFFFF OR color/white**

Is there any difference/affect in performance on color redraws? Pros/Cons ?

I have asked a few android theme developers and some say that using the #FFFFFFFF recommended as its basically telling it how it is, rather than using the color/white which is to call from another location.

Though I have asked then why in say for example Android Framework/res/values/colors, both formats are being used ?

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers, all of them made sense and were very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance reasons, no.

But, you will likely want a combination of the two.  You will define `color/white` in your styles and in the styles you will set `color/white` to #FFFFFFFF.

The reason for this is that you can reference the same white color that you defined in the styles everywhere in your app.  So if (when?) the day comes that your designer says "I don't want pure white anymore, I want a creamy off-white" you can just change the color in one place and you're done.  And if the name is no longer representative of what it is, you can do a global rename with just a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference/affect in performance on color redraws?
>   Pros/Cons ?

not really.

```
@color/white
```

retrieve an entry in your `colors.xml` file, that contains the colours in the hex format.

```
@android:color/
```

retrieve an entry in the `colors.xml` file provided by the framework

Answer (score 0):

`#FFFFFFFF` will make you have control over it.
`color/white` will have android/samsung/htc/lg control over it; they can override it with somewhat white or greyish in framework.

So, it depends if you want it to be in sync with the white globally in the users framework or not.